# Add Heading Before dynamically created form field Jquery .insertBefore

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, insert

I have a form that is dynamically created, so I can't edit the layout of the form itself. However, I want to add a title above one of the text input fields in the form. I have given that field a unique css ID and am using the following script to try and add my heading before it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('<h5 class="form_title">Calculate Return</h5>').insertBefore('#price');
</script>
```

For some reason this won't work though, can anyone think why that might be. Here is the page in question

http://www.theres-a-thought.com/client-yourdream/?page=property_submit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your page, I don't see where `#price` is defined.  Maybe it is added later via JS and i missed it..

You are using jquery in no-conflict mode, and you need to wrap your code in document ready..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('<h5 class="form_title">Calculate Return</h5>').insertBefore('#price');
});
</script>
```

Running this; however, has no affect on the page(from what i can see).

The code below works because the ID exists.  It isn't what you are trying to accomplish, but it should get you started.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('<h5 class="form_title">Calculate Return</h5>').insertBefore('#property_name');
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Add document ready to your code -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('<h5 class="form_title">Calculate Return</h5>').insertBefore('#price');
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Jay, for some reason that still didn't work. Any thoughts as to why? Perhaps I'm adding it in the wrong place in the script??

Comment: Your site seems to be not working right now - just getting code output. I'll look further when fixed.

Comment: @user2023235 has the answer - #price is not used as an id anywhere in your page, plus the document ready handler.